# Razor C# code to VB

Tags: vb.net, razor, c#-to-vb.net, named-parameters

I trying to convert this C# code VB.Net. its giving syntax error.

C#

```
@{
var grid = new WebGrid(source: data, 
                           defaultSort: "name",  
                           rowsPerPage: 30) 
}
```

VB.Net

```
@Code
Dim grid as new WebGrid(source: data, 
                           defaultSort: "name",  
                           rowsPerPage: 30); 
End Code
```

What is the correct say to convert this?

-SR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB.NET has a [different syntax for named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331620/differences-between-how-c-and-vb-handle-named-parameters) than does C#. (They were around in VB for a long time before they ever made their way into C#.)

You can rewrite the code like this:

```
Dim grid As New WebGrid(source := data, defaultSort := "name", rowsPerPage := 30)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for, just trying to learn VB syntax

Answer (score 0):

@sfgroups  ... Try out this tool, http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/